# Print an R help file vignette as output into an R HTML notebook

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I'm trying to print an R help file vignette in an R notebook chunk for output into an HTML file. I want the entire vignette to show up as output in the HTML notebook preview because it serves as a nice data dictionary for a quick regression example. Using `library(mlbench)`, I tried:

```
print(?BostonHousing2)
```

and I tried just calling

```
?BostonHousing2
```

in the code chunks, and neither of them output to the HTML file, they just populate in the Help tab inside of RStudio.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way (if I correctly understand what you want). But maybe not the best one.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Stéphane Laurent"
date: "29 février 2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(gbRd) # for Rd_fun
```

```{r, results='asis'}
Rd <- Rd_fun(help("pretty")) 
htmlfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
tools::Rd2HTML(Rd, htmlfile, package = "",
               stages = c("install", "render"))
htmllines <- readLines(htmlfile)
i <- grep("<body>", htmllines)
j <- grep("</body>", htmllines)
cat(htmllines[(i+1):(j-1)], sep = "\n")
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Noam Ross's solution](http://www.noamross.net/archives/2013-06-18-helpconsoleexample/), and modified with some of the code in Stéphane Laurent's answer, the following function can be used to return an HTML version of the help file

```
help_console <- function(topic, package,
                         format=c("text", "html", "latex", "Rd"),
                         before=NULL, after=NULL) {
  # topic - the command for which help is required
  # package - the package name with the required topic
  # format - output format
  # before - place code before the output e.g. "<blockquote>"
  # after - place code after the output e.g. "</blockquote>"

  # based on code by Noam Ross
  #  http://www.noamross.net/archives/2013-06-18-helpconsoleexample/
  # Stéphane Laurent
  #  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468080/
  #   print-an-r-help-file-vignette-as-output-into-an-r-html-notebook
  # and Michael Sumner (mdsumner)
  #  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495685/
  #   how-to-access-the-help-documentation-rd-source-files-in-r

  format <- match.arg(format)
  if (!is.character(topic)) topic <- deparse(substitute(topic))
  db <- tools::Rd_db(package)
  helpfile <- db[paste0(topic, ".Rd")][[1]]

  hs <- capture.output(
    switch(
      format,
      text = tools::Rd2txt(helpfile),
      html = tools::Rd2HTML(
        helpfile,
        package = "",
        stages = c("install", "render")
      ),
      latex = tools::Rd2latex(helpfile),
      Rd = tools:::prepare_Rd(helpfile)
    )
  )
  if (format == "html") {
    i <- grep("<body>", hs)
    j <- grep("</body>", hs)
    hs <- hs[(i+1):(j-1)]
  }
  hs <- c(before, hs, after)
  hs <- cat(hs, sep = "\n")
  invisible(hs)
}
```

Which then can be used as follow in a RMarkdown document, ready for knitting:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
help_console("pretty", "base", format = "html")
```
````

As usual, the R chunk needs to be set to `results = "asis"` to output to HTML.

This solution does not require the `gbRd` package.

For some strange reason, I can `Knit to html_vignette` from **RStudio**'s Knit dropdown, but *cannot* successfully `Build Document` from the **RStudio** menu with `Project Options - Build Tools - Roxygen Configure - Vignettes` enabled, with the error

```
Error:  Sections \title, and \name must exist and be unique in Rd files
```

thrown when trying to use the `help_console` function.

However, I was able to successfully able to create the HTML vignette and incorporate into a package with [A-breeze's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634056/how-to-include-an-html-vignette-in-a-binary-r-package), or building a source or binary package (building source/binary packages can be done from RStudio's "build" menu).